# nginx sub-domain mapping

Tags: django, configuration, nginx

I want to open xyz.abc.com in the browser but internally(using python-django), I want to map this to abc.com/xyz
The following nginx conf code works, but I don't want to redirect the user to this new url (abc.com/xyz)

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name xyz.abc.com;

    location / {
        rewrite ^ http://abc.com/xyz;
        break;
}
```

I have tried a lot of things including using proxy_pass but it's not working. 
How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert any 3rd level domain to 2nd level:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name ~^(?<domain>.*)\.abc\.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://abc.com/$domain$request_uri;
        break;
}
```

In your case try the next:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name xyz.abc.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://abc.com/xyz$request_uri;
        break;
}
```

About the **request_uri**: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule